# How can I set up a universal link for a url that has one complicated path?

Tags: ios, mobile-development

The URL in question is: https://staging.swatchbook.us/login?fromPage=login&token=flashcard_a1253b7c-f32e-402e-af0c-5148c2d9b9f6

We want our app to launch if the user taps login (that URL). The problem is that there seems to only be one path so we can't really do something like "/login/*". Here is our current AASA that does not work.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": ["9YLRJ9P8VS.swatchbookInc.SwatchBook"],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/password/reset/*",
                        "comment": "password/reset"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/register/*",
                        "comment": "register"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/redirectLogin/*",
                        "comment": "redirectLogin"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/acceptInvitation/*",
                        "comment": "acceptInvitation"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/login/*",
                        "comment": "login"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/collection/*",
                        "comment": "collection"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/swatch/*",
                        "comment": "swatch"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/user/*/preferences",
                        "comment": "userPreferences"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "appIDs": ["9YLRJ9P8VS.us.swatchbook.mixApp"],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/variant/*",
                        "comment": "variants redirection url"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "9YLRJ9P8VS.us.swatchbook.mixApp",
        ]
    }
}
```

We've tried "/login" "/login*" "login?fromPage" and none seem to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

EDIT: it seems that our AASA file is outdated on Apple's end. Is there a way to force a refresh?

Comment: See [alternate modes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-an-associated-domain) to enable developer mode and bypass Apple's CDN